# On-click functions for non-anchor non-button elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is there a way in JQuery or Javascript that we can click on an element like h2,h3,p,.. to execute a function?

Traditional on-click just for anchor tag and button tag.

Thank you.

Comment: need to click on h2 ? any kind of example can u give ?

Comment: Same way as any other onclick function.

Comment: I'm working on a classified project :D. By the way thanks for your comment. Have a nice day.

Comment: Given you've specifically mentioned jquery, I can't help feeling you haven't actually tried searching for "jquery click" which gives you a demo of almost exactly what you've just asked for

Comment: Maybe, I did search though, but had some confusing between Javascript JQuery and even HTML. Just a newbie though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$("h2").on("click", function(event){
    alert('!');
});
```

Comment: Holy! Thank you very much! Will accept the answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

Just use proper selector:

```
$("h2,h3,p").on("click", function(e){
   console.log("clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also une onClick if you want a particular tag to be used

HTML :

```
<h2 onClick="h2()">Random title</h2>
```

Javascript :

```
function h2() {
console.log("foo");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)